# Rspec Errors on Chapter 9.1 - Argument cannot contain nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

Hi guys I'm trying to solve the problem on Chapter 9 Ex 1 of Hartl's really awesome ROR tutorial. I've exhausted all Googling and am turning to trouble readers here for a solution at my problem here. I've ran a Rspec test on and its turning up the error

```
 User Pages edit page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
 # ./app/views/users/edit.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_edit_html_erb__1806936194471399240_70271188651260'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Most naturally  I've gone back to follow on my Sign Tutorial , looking up the edit.html.erb file and user_pages_spec.rb file but all seems to be just about right. Had a look on my routing (just in case anything went wrong) and users_controller but they loook fine too. Here are the codes

Edit.html.erb with line 6 being <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="span6 offset3">
   <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
```

Users_controller.rb

```
def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if 
      @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end    
end
```

user_pages_spec.rb line 61 being " before { visit edit_user_path(user) } "

```
describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end
end
```

Where would have gone wrong ?

Thanks so much guys !

Comment: Which line of your `edit.html.erb` is 6?

Comment: Hey Pavan thanks for the comment : in edit.html.erb its   <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem behind this because my

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

of the user_controller was within the private method which was why it did not return anything ...

Such a poor mistake I'm embarassed...

Hope this helps to save others some time ...